# NullPointerException when writing to Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nullpointerexception

I am trying to add an item to a user in my Firebase database but I keep getting a NullPointerException every time I try and access the location I want to write the data. This location does not yet exist (because I need to first write data to it); however, this was not a problem when adding a "userID" section and adding information underneath it, like so:

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
userReference = database.getReference("accounts");
DatabaseReference currentUserDB = userReference.child(user.getUid());

currentUserDB.child("name").setValue(name);
```

The above section of the code adds a key with the user ID and then adds the users name inside it. This is similar to what I want to do next.

What I would like to do is add a section called "item" and inside that add "first" with the value name. Like this [image: this].

Where the keys "item" and "first" don't exist until the user first clicks the button to run this code. This code should also work item "second" and so on.

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference dbR = database.getReference("accounts").child(uid);
reference = dbR.child("item");

DatabaseReference databaseReference = reference.child("test");

databaseReference.child("name").setValue(name);
```

I get a NullPointerException at this line:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = reference.child("test");
```

and I'm not sure why.

I am sure this has been answered in some form because it seems so simple, but I haven't seen anywhere that discusses writing two keys to the database at once.

Any help appreciated. My apologies if this is a duplicate.
Cheers

Edit: I know what a NullPointerException is, i just don't know why I'm getting one in this instance. The two sets of code are very similar and I'm not sure why the second code set gives me an error.

Comment: Please add the order in which you initialize those objects.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate of that. I know what a NPE is I just dont know why I'm not getting one.

Comment: That is the order they are initialized. I'm not sure I understand the question?

Comment: I don't think `DatabaseReference.child()` should ever return `null`. Can you show the entire error message + stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write your code like this:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    reference.child("accounts")
            .child("test")
            .child("item")
            .child("first")
            .child("name")
            .setValue(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible put your code here, it would help.

I think if "item" and "first" doesnt exist you can't use it as reference cause the node isnt there.

You need to use `reference = dbR.setValue("item")` first, and then you can use use as ref.